# Using SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to change the color of TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor, android-viewbinder

I'm developing an alarm clock app for android and I want to have displayed list of alarms on the main screen. Each row of this `ListView` is defined in xml file. And I want to have separate `TextViews` for each day of week. Program will check in sqlite db if for eg. value for `monday` is = 1 and then change color of this `TextView` to red. I have written this code, but that doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
private void fillData() {

    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = db.fetchAllAlarms();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_TIME, db.KEY_NAME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.time, R.id.alarmName };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter alarms =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.alarm_row, c, from, to);
        alarms.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            int dayOfWeekIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("mon");
            if (dayOfWeekIndex == columnIndex) {
                int color = cursor.getInt(dayOfWeekIndex);
                switch(color) {
                case 0: ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); break;
                case 1: ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.GRAY); break;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Android documentation on `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`:

> Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the
>   specified view. When binding is handled by this ViewBinder, this
>   method must return true. If this method returns false,
>   SimpleCursorAdapter will attempts to handle the binding on its own.

In other words, your implementation of `setViewValue` should not be specific to any one `View`, as `SimpleCursorAdapter` will make changes to each `View` (according to your implementation) when it populates the `ListView`. `setViewValue` is basically your chance to do whatever you wish with the data in your `Cursor`, including setting the color of your views. Try something like this,

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    
    // if this holds true, then you know that you are currently binding text to
    // the TextView with id "R.id.alarmName"
    if (view.getId() == R.id.alarmName) {
        final int dayOfWeekIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("day_of_week");
        final int color = cursor.getInt(dayOfWeekIndex);

        switch(color) {
        case 0: ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); break;
        case 1: /* ... */ break;
        case 2: /* ... */ break;
        /* etc. */
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that the above code assumes a column named `"day_of_week"` which holds an `int` value 0-6 (to specify the specific day of the week).

Comment: Honestly now is worse then before, because it crashes. at the begening it executes alarmNameIndex = cursorgetColumnIndex(db.KEY_NAME.toString()); and it becomes 1, then columnIndex becomes 1 after 2 iterations, and then suddenly columnIndex becomes -1

Comment: oh, sorry. It was my fault. I didn't changed yours "day_of_week_ to my "mon". But now the problem is the same. columnIndex is 1 or 2 during executing that function, but dayOfWeekIndex is 3, so it isn't working.

Comment: by the way, what exactly is "mon"...? does it simply hold "0" if the alarm is not set for monday, and 1 if it is set for monday?

Comment: also, i don't know why you think "dayOfWeekIndex" being equal to 3 is indicating that the code doesn't work... dayOfWeekIndex is never going to be equal to columnIndex because you never told the `SimpleCursorAdapter` to bind from the "mon" column

Comment: Yes "mon" hold "0" if alarm isn't set for monday and "1" if it is set for monday. So if mon is set for monday i want to change the color of TextView for monday. Main screen looks like this: http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/8468/snapshot1me.png

Comment: now I've changed to: 
String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_TIME, db.KEY_NAME, db.KEY_MON };
but still column isn't 3

Comment: ohhhhhh, ok i've been thinking you had a different layout all this time. could you post your XML layout (the custom list row one?)

Comment: what is "R.id.alarmName"...? i see no 3rd textview in your screenshot

Comment: OK! It worked! There was a problem with SimpleCursorAdapter, as you said I didn't bind it correctly so column was never == 3. Now it's ok with the code you provided. Thanks a lot for your patience and your time! in xml i have simply 9 text boxes set in relative layout, for time, alarmName, and 7 days. R.id.alarmName is the name of alarm. It should be above these days of week, but it was empty.

Comment: ahh... i see. adapters can be tough sometimes :). glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 2):

From the Android documentation on `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`:

> Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the
>   specified view. When binding is handled by this ViewBinder, this
>   method must return true. If this method returns false,
>   SimpleCursorAdapter will attempts to handle the binding on its own.

In other words, your implementation of `setViewValue` should not be specific to any one `View`, as `SimpleCursorAdapter` will make changes to each `View` (according to your implementation) when it populates the `ListView`. Your implementation should look something like this,

```
notes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int dayOfWeekIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("day_of_week");
        if (dayOfWeekIndex == columnIndex) {
            int color = cursor.getInt(dayOfWeekIndex);
            switch(color) {
            case 0: ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); break;
            case 1: /* ... */ break;
            case 2: /* ... */ break;
            /* etc. */
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that the above code assumes a column named `"day_of_week"` which holds an `int` value 0-6 (to specify the specific day of the week).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful, but I don't want to change each View, I only want to change one textview associated with specific day. And the second thing is that columnIndex has values of 1 and 2, but I have 10 columns in my cursor..

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what it is that is going wrong, but you should re-consider hard-coding int values in your code. for example, saying `if (columnIndex == 5)` is not good practice, because this code will break if you ever alter your database in the future. see my code for an example on how to change this (this also might be the reason why things aren't working for you...)

Comment: Yeah, I've done that as you have written, so I don't have hard-coded int values, but statement in 'if' condition is never true, because it checks only two first columns and I don't know why.

Comment: so wait, let me understand correctly... you want to update a _specific_ `View`s color IF one of the alarm's is set for a specific day of the week?

Comment: also, I don't understand where the `TextView`s are being displayed. if the `ListView` is being displayed on the main screen, then where are these seven `TextView`s you are talking about?

Comment: Yes. I have row layout defined in xml file in which I have textview for time, name of alarm, and 7 days of the week. And I have database in which I have for each alarm 7 columns for days (+ colums for time and name of course). Now I want to check in which days this alarm is active and change the color of these textview's to red for example.

Comment: All of views are in the ListView in each row.

Comment: is the code you posted updated... or have you changed it since you posted the question?

Comment: what does the column `db.KEY_MON` hold... from what I can understand from your code, it should hold each alarm's name, correct?

Comment: @ Alex Now it's updated. db.KEY_MON holds int value if monday is selected for alarm. It was there temporarily only to check if it reads value correctly