# Android: Read integer as string in a ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I currently have an application that contains a listView that is populated from the sqlite database. The ListView contains two texts views for each item, one for the name and one for the status. A status is displayed either by a 0 or a 1 like true or false. I would like to make each item that contains the number 0 or 1 as the status to display open or closed.

methods for the listview:

```
// Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // also added
    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Here is my listView code:

```
private void loadListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Locker getList = new Locker(this);
    getList.open();
    Cursor cursor = getList.getAllRows();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    // setup mapping
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { getList.KEY_LOCKERNUMBER,
            getList.KEY_STATUS };

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.tvLockerNumber, R.id.tvSatus };

    // create adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.itemlayout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs);

    // set the adapter
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInfo);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: "I would like to make each item that contains the number 0 or 1 as the status to display open or closed." What do you mean by open or closed? Are you talking about different layouts?

Comment: Within the list view currently its get the status variable from my database which can either be a 0 or a 1. I would like my list view to interpret those integers and display on the textview to say Open or Close.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement the method setViewValue of myCursorAdapter so you can set the textview to Open or Close when 1 or 0.

Take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658201/using-simplecursoradapter-viewbinder-to-change-the-color-of-textview) for an exmample. Also, look at the [developer's guide](http://bit.ly/1mOkatP) for more details.