# Append text to data returned from SQLite query before displaying in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am retrieving a set of results from an SQLite database and displaying it in a `ListView`. 
What I want to do is to append some text before the result value before showing it in the actual `ListView`.
For example, if I am getting a value `5` from the database, I want to display it as `Value = 5` in the `ListView`.

Here is the code that I am using for updating the `ListView`:

```html
private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllSubjects();

        String[] columns = new String[]{
                getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_SUBJECT,
                getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_SEMESTER,
                getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_ATTENDED,
                getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TOTAL,
                getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_PERCENT
        };

        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.sub_out,
                R.id.semester_out,
                R.id.attended_out,
                R.id.total_out,
                R.id.percent_out
        };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, cursor, columns, to, 0);
        subject_list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

What I had tried was the following modification to the `String[]` array:

```html
private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllVals();

        String[] columns = new String[]{
                "Val1" + getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_1,
                "Val2: " + getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_2,
                "Val3: " + getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_3,
                "Val4: " + getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_4,
                "Val5: " + getSubjectsDbAdapter.KEY_5
        };

        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.one,
                R.id.two,
                R.id.three,
                R.id.four,
                R.id.five
        };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, cursor, columns, to, 0);
        subject_list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

But that gave me the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'Val2: val2Val3: val3' does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252170/change-text-of-items-in-listview-when-it-is-displayed-using-simplecursoradapter).

```
Cursor allTaskcursor = databaseHelper.getAllTasks();
String[] from = {"name", "date"};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, allTaskcursor, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view.getId() == android.R.id.text2) {
            int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
            int date = cursor.getInt(getIndex);
            TextView dateTextView = (TextView) view;
            dateTextView.setText(date + " days");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
allTaskListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```